# Removing box shadow from element using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to remove the box shadow from an element which I defined in css like this:

```
.pagewrap .page { moz-box-shadow:0 1px 2px #fff,0 -1px 1px #666,inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px #fff,0 -1px 1px #666,inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);box-shadow:0 1px 2px #fff,0 -1px 1px #666,inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8); }
```

I use the following jquery to get rid of the box shadow, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
$('.pagewrap .page').css({'-webkit-box-shadow' : '', 'moz-box-shadow' : '', 'box-shadow' : ''});
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `-moz-box-shadow`, with a leading dash?

Comment: Also, all current versions of the modern browsers support the box-shadow property without the vendor prefix

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To override these styles, you need to explicitly specify `'none'` instead of just `''`:

```
$('.pagewrap .page').css({'-webkit-box-shadow' : 'none', '-moz-box-shadow' : 'none', 'box-shadow' : 'none'});
```

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/8PV5v/

And as Frédéric points out, `moz-box-shadow` should be `-moz-box-shadow` - replace this everywhere you've used it.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
$(".pagewrap .page").css("box-shadow", "none");
```